# Segfaults with all of the `if/else-if/else-if` statements but not when commenting one of them

Tags: c, gtk

I have a tricky one here I just can't seem to figure out.  When using the whole `if/else-if/else-if` it segfaults if the argument in the vector doesn't exist.  If the argument exists then it runs fine it seems.   When I comment out one of the `else-if` blocks then it runs ok it seems also.

Edited:

```
void
priority_arg_create (gchar *arg)
{
    gchar **argvp;
    gint argcp;
    gint i;
    gint j;

    argvp = get_arg_vector ();
    argcp = 0;
    i = 0;

    /* obtain arg count not including the `NULL` terminator. */
    while (argvp[argcp])
    {
        argcp++;
    }

    g_print ("From `rt_priority.c` line 42: %d\n", argcp);

    /* Here we look for the jack arg `-Px` with the for loop then the if
    statement. If it does not exist then we add it to arg vector with
    `else/if` statement. */
    for (i = 0; i <= argcp; i++)
    {
        if ((i == argcp -1) && (strncmp (argvp[i], "-P", 2) != 0))
        {
            g_print ("From `rt_priority.c` line 65\n");

            /* Add space to arg vector for the jackd arg `-R`. */
            argcp = argcp + 1;

            /* If realtime arg exists then place priority arg right
            after that.*/
            if ((strncmp (argvp[1], "-r", 2) == 0) ||
                (strncmp (argvp[1], "-R", 2) == 0))
            {
                /* Here we move the args over one to place `-Px` as the
                third arg in the vector. */
                for (j = argcp; j >= 2; j--)
                {
                    argvp[j] = argvp[j - 1];
                }

                argvp[2] = arg;
            }
            else
            {
                /* Here we move the args over one to place `-Px` as the
                second arg in the vector. */
                for (j = argcp; j >= 1; j--)
                {
                    argvp[j] = argvp[j - 1];
                }

                argvp[1] = arg;
            }

            break;
        }
        else if (g_strcmp0 (argvp[i], arg) == 0)
        {
            g_print ("From `rt_priority.c` line 51: %d\n", i);

            break;
        }
        /* If `priority arg` is found but the number does not match
        execute else/if statement. */
        else if (strncmp (argvp[i], "-P", 2) == 0)
        {              
            argvp[i] = arg;

            break;
        }
    }     
    file_input (argvp, argcp);
}
```

And here's the output of `g_print ()` inside the `for ()` loop
with `line 56` showing `argvp` and `line 57` showing `argcp` :

```
From `rt_priority.c` line 42: 6
From `rt_priority.c` line 56: /usr/bin/jackd
From `rt_priority.c` line 57: 6
From `rt_priority.c` line 56: -dalsa
From `rt_priority.c` line 57: 6
From `rt_priority.c` line 56: -dhw:M2496
From `rt_priority.c` line 57: 6
From `rt_priority.c` line 56: -r48000
From `rt_priority.c` line 57: 6
From `rt_priority.c` line 56: -p128
From `rt_priority.c` line 57: 6
From `rt_priority.c` line 56: -n2
From `rt_priority.c` line 57: 6
From `rt_priority.c` line 56: (null)
From `rt_priority.c` line 57: 6
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Edited:

Here's the `get_arg_vector ()` function:

```
gchar **argvp
get_arg_vector ()
{
    gchar cmd[128];
gchar **argvp;
gchar *contents;
gint argcp;
gsize size;

/* Create path to file `.jackdrc` using `g_sprintf ()`. */
g_sprintf (cmd, "%s/.jackdrc", g_getenv ("HOME"));

/* Check if file path exists. */
if (g_file_test (cmd, G_FILE_TEST_EXISTS) == FALSE)
{
    g_print ("File doesn't exist.  Create file.");

    return NULL;
}

g_file_get_contents (cmd, &contents, &size, NULL);
g_shell_parse_argv (contents, &argcp, &argvp, NULL);

return argvp;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last **else-if** is supposed to resize the **argvp**-array when the end is reached in the **for**-loop. The **if** and the first **else-if** read the current value from the **argvp** (which might be 0, which is an error). Probably the code started out containing only the last **else-if**, and the other **if/else-ifs** were inserted later. 
Change the order of the **else-if**, so that the last runs before the other ones, then it should work.

To make space for one additional element in the array returned by get_arg_vector simply realloc it to contain one more element; i.e. just before returning the argvp, at the end of get_arg_vector, insert:

```
  ....
  argvp = g_realloc (argvp, (argcp + 2) * sizeof *argvp);
  return argvp;
}
```

The array normally contains (argcp+1) elements, so (argcp+2) makes it one element bigger.

Comment: I changed the order as suggested and I still get the segfault.  I also changed the comparison in the first `if ()` statement but again still same error.

Comment: Actually let me correct myself.  I'm getting undefined behavior and sometimes get a `corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000001ddac20` error or `realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001b7efc0` error.

Comment: The problem is likely with the get_arg_vector() function. For the code to work, it must return an array that is at least one element bigger than what is required; because it has to have enough space for the extra argument that is inserted. If it has not, the function will overwrite memory at the end of the array (which results in the error with the realloc() because malloc() puts its own data at the end). The line with the argcp = argcp + 1; in it, does not actually resize the array, it only treats it as a longer array, the array must be long enough for that already.

Comment: rassahah: I added the `get_arg_vector ()` function in OP.  How would I add an element to the returned `**argvp`?  I'm a little uncertain on how do this.

Comment: i augmented the answer on how to do that.

Comment: ahhhh!  I ok I was trying to figure out how to memcpy but this seems much simpler.  Thanks rassahah!!!

Comment: rassahah:  When I use this in the code I can only get the [0] element in the vector and then it breaks when NULL is reached which means NULL is [1] which isn't what I want it to do.  Am I supposed strcpy here as well?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for (i = 0; i <= argcp + 1; i++)
```

is scary. We know that `argv[argcp]` is `NULL`, from the loop above that did the search. Thus, this loop oversteps that by *two*, from using `<=` *and* `+ 1`.

Print the current index as you loop, and also print the value of `argcp`.

Comment: Print from `for ()` is above in OP.